# How to jumble words with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a PHP script that will take 4 words and change all letters to uppercase and shuffle the letters. All words can only take 4-7 words and no numbers.

Right now, my code recognizes if the words don't fit the 4-7 restriction and says error if the word contains numbers.

I have two problems:

1. For some reason, the code only recognizes the Error for word 1, but not the others.
2. If I add the correct words, the shuffle function doesn't work and after I press submit, I just get an error.

I can't figure out what's wrong. Any suggestions:

HTML

```
    <form action="process_JumbleMaker.php" method="post">
        Word 1: <input type="text" name="Word1" /><br />
        Word 2: <input type="text" name="Word2" /><br />
        Word 3: <input type="text" name="Word3" /><br />
        Word 4: <input type="text" name="Word4" /><br />

        <input type="reset" value="Clear Form" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Form" />

    </form>

   </body>
```

PHP

```
   <?php

        function displayError($ﬁeldName, $errorMsg) {
            global $errorCount;
                echo "Error for \"$ﬁeldName\": $errorMsg \n";
                ++$errorCount;
        }

        function validateWord($data, $ﬁeldName) {
            global $errorCount;
            if (empty($data)) {
                displayError($ﬁeldName,"This ﬁeld is required");
                $retval = "";
            } else { 
                $retval = trim($data);
                $retval = stripslashes($retval);
             
                if ((strlen($retval)<4) || (strlen($retval)>7)) {
                    displayError($ﬁeldName,"Words must be at least four and at most seven letters long");
                }

                if (preg_match("/^[a-z]+$/i",$retval)==0) {
                    displayError($ﬁeldName,"Words must be only letters");
                }
            }
            $retval = strtoupper($retval);
            $retval = str_shufﬂe($retval);
            return($retval);
        }

        $errorCount = 0;
        $words = array();
        $words[] = validateWord($_POST['Word1'], "Word 1");
        $words[] = validateWord($_POST['Word2'], "Word 2");
        $words[] = validateWord($_POST['Word3'], "Word 3");
        $words[] = validateWord($_POST['Word4'], "Word 4");

        if ($errorCount>0) {
             echo "Please use the \"Back\" button to re-enter the data. \n";
        }
        else {
             $wordnum = 0;
             foreach ($words as $word)
             echo "Word ".++$wordnum.": $word\n";
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: I also noticed there is some weird character when your calling `str_shuffle`  The 'fl' in `shuffle` is combined and not individual characters.

Comment: @DawsonIrvine I just get - this page isn't working. But, it only does that when the words are correct. If words contain numbers then it outputs the error message that it's supposed to, but only for Word1, not the others. It doesn't catch the errors in Words 2-4.

Comment: @DawsonIrvine you're absolutely right about the "fl" !!! I don't know what happened there, but that was the problem!

Comment: I suggest to rewrite this peace of code. Don't use globals, aggregate errors, validate function cannot manipulating string and returning new value. Why do you manipulate words in case words are invalid?

Comment: `I just get - this page isn't working`...turn on error reporting, then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spelling error for the `str_shuffle` function call, the `f` and `l` have been combined into a ligature instead of the single letters, changing the function call so single letter instead of the ligature will fix your error.

```php
$retval = str_shuffle($retval); // Right
$retval = str_shufﬂe($retval);  // Wrong
```